# checking for activity count for each and every sql in a sql file from a bteq script

Tags: teradata

I am trying to check the activity count for each and every sql present in a sql file which is run using a bteq script in Unix . 
Following is the code snippet I am trying to use but the activity count is checked for the last sql but not for all sql's in **test.sql** which has say 5 sql's .

```
.logon -----/&&&&&,******
.os rm /home/lankirn/venkat/output.txt
.os touch /home/lankirn/venkat/output.txt
.export FILE /home/lankirn/venkat/output.txt
.run FILE=/home/lankirn/venkat/test.sql

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN .GOTO Continue
ELSE
.os rm /home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
.os touch /home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
.EXPORT DATA FILE =/home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
SELECT 'Data not Found';
.LABEL Continue
.os rm /home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
.os touch /home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
.EXPORT DATA FILE =/home/lankirn/venkat/pass.txt
SELECT 'Data Found';

.QUIT
```

Kindly help me to check the activity count of each and every sql so that i can export if the sql is returning any rows or not to a text file

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You have to insert activity_count checking after each query in your test.sql. 
Or else you can simply run your select queries first without export mode on..check activity_count of each query and then trigger the export.